# How to insert Date into mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc, java.util.date

I am trying to insert a Date into mySql db . I accept date as a string and parse it to util.Date then convert it to sql.Date and then I am inserting into database . Here is my code

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
String mydate=dsd.getDoa();
Date mydate2=format.parse(mydate);
java.sql.Date sqlDate;
sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(mydate2.getTime());
System.out.println("Date"+sqlDate.getDate()+"Month"+sqlDate.getMonth()+"Year"+sqlDate.getYear());

....

int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into device_sales_details values("+sqlDate+"));
```

The error is as follow ,

`com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '1980' for column 'device_sales_details_DOA' at row 1`

The `Sysout` prints as follow for input `22/12/2014`

`Date22Month11Year114` How to solve this problem , can any one help me in this please.

Comment: How is the date stored in your database?

Comment: What is output of `desc device_sales_details` in mysql?

Comment: @VimalBera in desc the field is of type date

Comment: as to your title question and if your date column in mysql is date type, you don't need to convert java.sql.Date sqlDate;.You should directly insert java.util.Date value to mysql.

Comment: @Harry I am using `sqlyog` and yes it is showing `2014-10-10` dates.

Comment: @YeWin I tried , it showed error . .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). It's almost never correct to use string concatenation to create SQL code to send through JDBC.

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into device_sales_details values(?)");
ps.setDate(1, sqlDate);
int i = ps.executeUpdate();
```

More about not using string concatenation here: http://bobby-tables.com

---

Separately, it's generally best to specify the columns when doing an insert, e.g.: `insert into device_sales_details (columnName) values (?)`

Comment: Yes Thank you , it solved my problem, I tried with `PreparedStatement` but I didnt get why my `sysout` that kind of output.